# How to check if nested list is present and unnest if present?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nested

I have a single row df that looks like this:

```
id         tags
1         [[[band_music, fun], tv], movies]
```

Sometimes the df can look like this depending on the source:

```
id         tags
1         [[[band_music, fun], tv]
```

or like this:

```
id         tags
1         [band_music, fun]
```

or like this:

```
id         tags
1         fun
```

How can I check the column if the nested lists are present and unnest them so they are like this:

or like this:

```
id         tags
1         [band_music, fun,movies,tv]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `findall`

```
df.tags.astype(str).str.findall("'([^']*)'")
0    [band_music, fun, tv]
Name: tags, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import re
df['tags'][1] = re.split(',', str(df['tags'][1]).replace('[','').replace(']', ''))
```

Output:

```
id  tags
1   ['band_music', 'fun', 'tv', 'movies']
```

Comment: @RustyShackleford this function limit with one row , also you do not have list , your column type is string

Comment: @W-B thank you for the hint. So I can do a string replace to achieve the same objective without the re library?

Comment: You just need a for loop to generalize my solution